# How to read table in sql script with pandas?

Tags: sql, pandas

I have a .sql script.

The script first checks function existence, then create a function if not exist.

It then declares variables.

Finally, it executes a query.

The script can produce correct result when executing in sql server management studio.

I used pandas to read the table:

```
with open('query.sql', 'r') as f:
    query = f.read()

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn_str)
```

But it returns

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near \'GO\'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]\'CREATE FUNCTION\' must be the first statement in a query batch. (111); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@number". (137); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context. (178); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near \'GO\'. (102)')
```

What can I do?

Comment: have you checked your connection string

Comment: yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pd.read_sql`

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM table_name ",connection_string)
```

so in your case

```
df = pd.read_sql(query, conn_str)
```